# Add value to computed column from a function that returns a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table that when a row is inserted, a computed column
calculates a commission value. I have wrapped the logic for this calculation into a function that returns a table. the function is a table-valued function.

what I thought I could do is

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CostChange] ADD Commission  
AS (SELECT TOP 1 Value 
    FROM fn_WesleyTest(CostId, BookingId, ChangeDate))
GO
```

But I get an error

```
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Is it possible to overcome this?

Will I have to change the return value of my function?

Comment: Why return a dataset just to top it? Why not return the top 1 value from your function?

Comment: Or create a new function to run similar to the original, in case it's used elsewere?

Comment: Sounds good, but I might just create a scalar function version of my table valued function.